# pythonxy can't be reinstalled or uninsalled

Tags: python, installation, pythonxy

For convenience, I am applying pythonxy

But when I try to reload or uninstall，log2del has been in the process,program stoped there

I can not reinstall or uninsall

Comment: This is far too vague to do anything with. Show us what you typed and what output you got.

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple way, delete the pythonxy directory (same as c:\python2.6),
then run pythonxy.exe again.

Comment: really? but there are many registration information in regedit.And many log2del.exe in python's site packages

Comment: when you reinstall pythonxy, all registration information will be updated... maybe..